# CSS3 column-count with floating divs and merged columns

Tags: css, html, merge, floating

I'm trying to achieve effect like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzuDo.jpg

As you can see, there is six columns (for me 4 is enough). There's some floating divs and image spanning on 4 columns. Using following code, in Chromium (Chrome) inserted div's width is limited to column's width.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfKE7.png

```
<div style="column-count: 4; -moz-column-count:4; -webkit-column-count:4; text-align: justify">
    <p>Header</p><hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero. Proin vitae magna vitae leo auctor consectetur. Pellentesque tempor pretium leo at volutpat. Nunc ultricies, est id ultrices pulvinar, nisl nunc porttitor nisi, aliquet pulvinar dolor neque sed lacus. Integer a risus quis nunc rutrum pellentesque. Praesent non ligula massa, nec gravida mauris. Quisque vitae libero nec augue sollicitudin gravida. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum porttitor, tortor ultricies lacinia gravida, nibh purus ultrices lacus, sed tempus augue ligula ac tortor. Proin urna tortor, tempus quis commodo id, eleifend ut augue. Nulla sit amet dolor tellus. Maecenas et pharetra tellus. Vivamus auctor odio id est imperdiet in tincidunt felis gravida. Vestibulum ultricies mauris ut dolor vulputate lacinia. In imperdiet urna a neque sollicitudin dictum sit amet ut tortor. Duis commodo volutpat mauris, quis euismod magna mattis non. Duis dapibus, felis eu bibendum ultricies, erat urna accumsan sapien, eu congue magna neque in massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla nec pretium sem. Proin aliquet nisl at orci cursus auctor. Praesent lacus quam, aliquet at vestibulum nec, euismod sit amet dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam fringilla tincidunt tincidunt. Integer tincidunt vehicula cursus. Quisque sed est auctor arcu ultricies iaculis eget id justo. Sed suscipit tellus et purus dignissim tristique. Ut non purus arcu, sed imperdiet odio. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        Mauris in magna orci. 

        <div style="float: left; width: 700px; height: 200px; background-color: gray">
            ff

        </div>
        Etiam leo lectus, accumsan at imperdiet sit amet, tincidunt ac tortor. Aenean tellus est, condimentum vitae scelerisque tempus, cursus et nisi. Vivamus ligula lacus, viverra id sodales quis, tempus in lectus. In ut ipsum libero. Aenean vitae orci ligula, non ultricies mauris. Donec metus dolor, feugiat ut blandit vitae, lobortis nec erat. Praesent sapien diam, egestas sit amet commodo a, varius at nulla. Vestibulum fermentum auctor porttitor. Vivamus tristique enim bibendum nulla consectetur molestie. Vivamus lacus velit, dignissim at iaculis id, sodales volutpat odio. Sed mollis consectetur aliquam. Cras rhoncus, nulla non congue porttitor, sapien ipsum lacinia ipsum, pharetra tincidunt arcu ligula id justo. Praesent nec enim tellus, eu aliquam orci.Integer lacinia accumsan nisl at tristique. Sed eget aliquam ipsum. In et magna ut erat posuere ultrices rutrum eget nulla. Nullam mauris nibh, sollicitudin eu aliquet sit amet, pulvinar sit amet tortor. Nunc at nulla sed urna pretium tristique eget quis massa. Quisque ultricies sagittis orci, sed dignissim ante egestas varius. Vivamus et ipsum libero, sagittis euismod enim. Donec volutpat feugiat orci, ut pellentesque nulla sodales gravida. Nulla egestas cursus pharetra. Praesent varius nibh vitae ligula auctor at sollicitudin lacus dapibus. Donec condimentum porttitor sem ac auctor. Mauris a nunc sit amet eros ornare accumsan. Nullam mauris purus, vestibulum id imperdiet sit amet, imperdiet id ante. Nullam nibh leo, pharetra eget fringilla nec, lobortis quis mauris. Fusce varius nulla non orci dapibus ut convallis dolor dictu
        Duis bibendum, dui sit amet sagittis scelerisque, lectus eros luctus dui, a rhoncus justo nisl sed lectus. Proin placerat suscipit lectus id malesuada. Vestibulum vitae nisl et orci fermentum facilisis. Pellentesque malesuada lacinia tristique. Mauris posuere lorem vitae dolor imperdiet porttitor. Maecenas eu tortor sem. Donec non eros dolor, sed interdum magna. Vivamus id commodo urna. Curabitur dapibus bibendum tincidunt. Praesent tincidunt consectetur metus, ut placerat sem volutpat interdum. Praesent sit amet posuere ipsum. Nunc posuere dolor quis erat pulvinar vitae ornare nibh ultricies. Vestibulum molestie porttitor mauris sed viverra. Nunc rutrum rhoncus lacus ac tincidunt. Nam at arcu ut erat pharetra porttitor. Fusce accumsan dui eget diam placerat vel sodales nisl feugiat.In consectetur orci eu velit porta non tristique velit faucibus. Etiam ac pellentesque sapien. Cras bibendum lorem in felis commodo nec pellentesque mauris fringilla. Maecenas magna augue, facilisis eu dignissim nec, interdum et enim. Pellentesque auctor sapien eu augue volutpat sit amet pretium ipsum vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam ut leo eros. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam tortor dolor, molestie at vestibulum nec, dignissim ut est. Donec iaculis vulputate purus et mattis. Morbi pulvinar accumsan mollis. Nulla a est lacus. Ut nisl enim, accumsan ut accumsan et, ultricies sit amet nulla. Nunc lacus purus, cursus et vulputate eget, pharetra id sem.
        Mauris in magna orci. Etiam leo lectus, accumsan at imperdiet sit amet, tincidunt ac tortor. Aenean tellus est, condimentum vitae scelerisque tempus, cursus et nisi. Vivamus ligula lacus, viverra id sodales quis, tempus in lectus. In ut ipsum libero. Aenean vitae orci ligula, non ultricies mauris. Donec metus dolor, feugiat ut blandit vitae, lobortis nec erat. Praesent sapien diam, egestas sit amet commodo a, varius at nulla. Vestibulum fermentum auctor porttitor. Vivamus tristique enim bibendum nulla consectetur molestie. Vivamus lacus velit, dignissim at iaculis id, sodales volutpat odio. Sed mollis consectetur aliquam. Cras rhoncus, nulla non congue porttitor, sapien ipsum lacinia ipsum, pharetra tincidunt arcu ligula id justo. Praesent nec enim tellus, eu aliquam orci.Integer lacinia accumsan nisl at tristique. Sed eget aliquam ipsum. In et magna ut erat posuere ultrices rutrum eget nulla. Nullam mauris nibh, sollicitudin eu aliquet sit amet, pulvinar sit amet tortor. Nunc at nulla sed urna pretium tristique eget quis massa. Quisque ultricies sagittis orci, sed dignissim ante egestas varius. Vivamus et ipsum libero, sagittis euismod enim. Donec volutpat feugiat orci, ut pellentesque nulla sodales gravida. Nulla egestas cursus pharetra. Praesent varius nibh vitae ligula auctor at sollicitudin lacus dapibus. Donec condimentum porttitor sem ac auctor. Mauris a nunc sit amet eros ornare accumsan. Nullam mauris purus, vestibulum id imperdiet sit amet, imperdiet id ante. Nullam nibh leo, pharetra eget fringilla nec, lobortis quis mauris. Fusce varius nulla non orci dapibus ut convallis dolor dict
    </p>                
</div>
```

On Firefox effect is broken too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rTHN.png

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You are talking about "floating divs" but you are using the CSS3 column module. Which way do you want to go?

Comment: This one which will give final result as it's shown.

Comment: You should point out what your problem is in doing so…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSS3 Multi-column layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol) provides the [column-span](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-span) property which "makes it possible for an element to span across several columns".
Unfortunately this property can assume only the values "all" or "none" (so, for example, if you're using a 4 columns layout, you can't span an element on 2 columns only) and can't be applied to floating or absolutely positioned elements.
In a [previous version](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-multicol-20010118/) of the W3C specifications, the `column-span` property could also assume an integer value (to specify exactly how many columns the element spans), but this option is not present in the latest version of the W3C specifications; the old specifications also provided support for floating elements between columns, but this feature has also been removed from the latest specifications.
On the web you can find several tutorials about the CSS3 Multi-Column layout module; in my opinion one of the best is [this one](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-css3-multiple-column-layout-module/) which, even if a bit old (november 2011), contains some useful examples and further references.
Be aware that the CSS3 Multi-column module is not supported on all browsers (see [this page](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn) for further details), so if you're looking for a cross-browser solution this may not be the best choice.
That said, I've tried to achieve your desired result by using some floating divs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #leftblock { 
            width: 66%;
            margin-right: 10px;
            float: left;
        }
        #rightblock { 
            width: 32%;
            float: left;
        }
        .lefttext { 
            column-count: 2; 
            -moz-column-count: 2; 
            -webkit-column-count: 2; 
            text-align: justify;
        }
        #righttext {
            column-count: 2; 
            -moz-column-count: 2; 
            -webkit-column-count: 2; 
            text-align: justify;
        }
        #image1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        #image2 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        h3 {
            color: blue;
        }
        h4 {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        p {
            margin-top: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .column1 {
            float: left; 
            width: 50%;
        }
        .column2 {
            float: right; 
            width: 49%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftblock">
            <div id="image1"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="column1">
                    <div>
                        <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.</b></p>
                        <h3>Author</h3>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lefttext">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        </p>                
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        </p>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column2">
                    <div class="lefttext">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        </p>                
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        </p>                
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                        </p>                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightblock">
            <div id="righttext">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                </p>                
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                </p>                
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                </p>                
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget mi a odio dapibus ornare. Phasellus magna lacus, pharetra scelerisque accumsan nec, feugiat ac libero.
                </p>                
            </div>
            <div id="image2"></div>
        </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

The main drawback of this solution is that you have to carefully "balance" the length of the text in each div to obtain the same (or almost the same) height.
I've tested this page on Chromium, Opera and Firefox; since I'm working on Linux I can't say if it also works on Internet Explorer (and it probably won't).
I'm aware that this may not be the best solution at all, but I hope that it can be a starting point for further experimenting.

Comment: I'm accepting your anwser because it's good to know that it was implemented in past but removed.